# Django dynamically display a list but ignore some items

Tags: html, django

I am trying to show a list of groups on the sidebar on my html using Django. The first item will always be "all". so when I tranverse through all the groups/subreddits, I would first display "all" and then display the rest. however, when I display the rest and when it hits "all" again, instead of doing nothing, it seems to be printing a empty line because later when I display it in forms, I notice that I have a blank cell. I wonder how do I make sure that it just ignores "all" and goes on to display the next group without the empty space. Here is the code:

```
    <div class="post" id="title"><h4>Groups </h4></div>

    {% for sub in subreddits %}

        {% if sub.name == 'all' %}
            <div class="post"> <a href="{% url 'sub_detail' pk=sub.pk %}">{{ sub.name }}</a></div>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}


    {% for sub in subreddits %}
        <div class="post">
            {% if sub.name != 'all' %}
                <a href="{% url 'sub_detail' pk=sub.pk %}">{{ sub.name }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show your subreddits included in context?
I guess, it is an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

Think about what will get rendered when `sub.name == 'all'` - the `<div>` is currently outside the if tag, so was getting displayed regardless. You'll get this:

```
<div class="post">

</div>
```

This is probably why you're getting an extra line.

#### The solution

Move the `<div>` inside your if tag:

```
    {% for sub in subreddits %}
        {% if sub.name != 'all' %}
            <div class="post">
                <a href="{% url 'sub_detail' pk=sub.pk %}">{{ sub.name }}</a> 
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This way when `sub.name == 'all'`, nothing is rendered at all.

Comment: @llu13701Glad to help. If you're happy with the answer, please click the tick to 'accept' it, and upvote if you like :)